# Getting error when generating unlocked package version

Tags: unlocked-package, second-generation-packaging, sfdx-error

I'm trying to create 2nd gen unlocked package version for a Trigger framework which is custom metadata driven. Every time I try to generate a version i'm getting error that custom fields in metadata types object doesn't exists because of which it also throws error related to dependent class invalid

```
    Multiple errors occurred:
    (1) MyTestClass: Field does not exist: AD__r on metadata_type__mdt
    (2) MyTestClass: Field does not exist: AD__c on metadata_type__mdt
    (3) MyTestClass: Field does not exist: Order__c on metadata_type__mdt
  (117) MyClassFlowClearBypass: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class MyTriggerHandler : Variable does not exist: Before_Update__c
```

Comment: Did you actually include those fields in the Unlocked Package?

Comment: @sfdcfox yes, I have included all the fields and metadata type objects in the package. I'm successfully able to deploy my branch into a scratch org but not able to generate package version

Comment: I'd double-check that. It's easy enough to forget to include the files in the repo. It doesn't matter if they're in the Scratch Org, because the repo/local files are the source of truth. Try `sfdx force:source:pull`.

Comment: Any resolution to this? I am getting this now. Can also push to scratch org fine but cannot create a package version. Tried pulling down what was pushed to the scratch org but that did not alleviate the issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelSchirger I ended up deleting the package id and generated a new package id which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try rename the package folder and update the path setting in packageDirectories, it works for me, not sure why tho